# Do symmetric matrices (over the reals) always represent a self adjoint operator regardless of basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

From Axler, the real theorem states:
[image]

Now in introductory linear algebra, we learn that symmetric matrices are diagonalizable, and it turns out that this is just a specific case of the real spectral theorem because symmetric matrices represents a self-adjoint operator (over the reals).

Now the question I have is did we assume implicitly that we were working with an orthonormal basis? Because the transpose of the matrix represents the self-adjoint of the operator (over the reals) , but this is only true if we had an orthonormal basis.

So is it possible to have a symmetric matrix over some non orthonormal basis such that we can never change the basis to be orthonormal while still having the matrix be symmetric. In that case the matrix would not represent any self-adjoint operator and the real spectral theorem would no longer apply correct?

Comment: We are assuming we are working with the $e_i$ basis.

Comment: A transformation that has a symmetric matrix relative to some **non**-orthonormal basis is not necessarily self-adjoint.