Diagonal matrix two-sided multiplication
If $D$ is a diagonal matrix, and $D=ADB$, where $A,B$ are invertible matrices. Can we conclude $A=B^T$? All matrices are real. $D$ is nonzero but not necessarily invertible. If that's true, suppose $D$ is invertible, can we further conclude $A=B^T=B^{-1}$? Thanks.
Background: I'm trying to prove "a symmetric operator on Euclidean space only has symmetric matrix form under an orthonormal basis". That is, if $<Ax,y>=<x, Ay>$ for all $x,y$ and if $B$ is an arbitrary basis, then the matrix form $A_B$ of $A$ is symmetric iff $B$ is orthonormal. Then it leads me to the question. My attempt was the following.
The matrix form of symmetry condition $<Ax,y>=<x,Ay>$, under basis $B$ is that $A_B^T<B,B>=<B,B>A_B$. But $<B,B>=B^TB$, so if assuming $A_B^T=A_B$, we then have $A_B=(B^TB)A_B(B^TB)^{-1}$. Suppose $A_B=P^T D_{A,B}P$, where $D_{A,B}$ is diagonal and $P$ is invertible, which is always possible. Then we arrive at
$$D_{A,B}=\left({P^T}^{-1}B^TBP^T\right) D_{A,B}\left(P B^{-1}{B^T}^{-1}P^{-1}\right),$$
which is exactly the form of the question above.
As the answers show, both of these propositions are false.

One does not necessarily conclude that $A = B^{\mathrm{T}}$. Let
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 5 \\
3 & 7
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
B = \begin{bmatrix}
-7 & -5 \\
-3 & -2
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
D = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It is easy to check that $ADB = D$ but that $A \neq B^{\mathrm{T}}$. Note that it is also true that $A \neq B^{-1}$.

The user who asked the question wanted to show that "if $\langle Ax,y \rangle = \langle x,Ay \rangle$ for all $x$, $y$ and if $B$ is an arbitrary basis, then the matrix form $A_B$ of $A$ is symmetric iff $B$ is orthonormal". Unfortunately, this is not true. The "if" part is true, but the "only if" part is not necessarily true. See Desperado's answer for more information.

Thanks! Made some updates on why I ask this question, can you please comment on that?

No, take for example $D=I_n$, $A=2I_n$ and $B=\frac 12 I_n$, then $ADB=I_n=D$; but $A\neq B^T$.
Edit: About the question in the background comment. It is not an "if and only if". Let $A$ be the identity map, then for each basis $B$ the matrix $A_B=I_n$ is symmetric, so $B$ is not necessarily an orthonormal basis.
What holds is the other direction: if $B$ is orthonormal, then $A_B$ is symmetric.

Thanks. Does this mean there's always $A=B^{-1}$?

No, see @Juliamisto's answer.

Thanks! Made some updates on why I ask this question, can you please comment on that?

@user760, just made some comment.

Thanks. Btw, I started doing this because of the comment by Ben Grossman under question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4204756/416552. Now I realize they said "not necessarily". How silly am I...

Assume $D=\begin{pmatrix}I_n&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$, $A^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}A_1&A_2\\0&A_4\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}B_1&0\\B_3&B_4\end{pmatrix}$,
where all $A_i$ and $B_j$ and $0$ are $n\times n$ matrices. It is easy to check that
$A^{-1}D=DB$ iff $A_1=B_1$, so $A_2$, $A_4$, $B_3$ and $B_4$ can be whatever you want ($A_1$ and $A_4$ invertible, of course), which means neither $A^{-1}=B$ nor $A^T=B$ necessarily stands.
